# How do I loop through a JSON list?

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple items in my JSON list. I want to loop through it and display it on my page. I can't seem to get to the next object though.

```
{
"room":[
    {"campusName":"A",
     "buildingCode":"B",
     "roomNumber":"208",
     "times":["7-8", "9-10"]
}],

"room2":[
{"campusName":"C",
  "buildingCode":"D",
  "roomNumber":"208",
  "times":["7-8", "9-10"
 ]}
]}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    $.each(data.room, function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            $("ul").append("<li>campus: "+this['campusName']+"</li><li>building: "+this['buildingCode']+"</li><li>times: "+this.times+"</li>");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try looping through `data` instead of `data.room`

Comment: You don't loop through a "JSON list" because there is no such thing. You parse the JSON **string(!)** and then you loop through the objects and arrays you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.each(data, ..)` --> Each element will be:

```
"room":[
    {"campusName":"A",
     "buildingCode":"B",
     "roomNumber":"208",
     "times":["7-8", "9-10"]
}]
```

Then, `this[0]` will provide the object you need to construct your `li`:

```
$.each(data, function(){
            $("ul").append("<li>campus: "+this[0]['campusName']+"</li><li>building: "+this[0]['buildingCode']+"</li><li>times: "+this[0].times+"</li>");
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcn282h2/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var list = '';

$.each(data, function (i, root) {
  $.each(root, function (i, el) {
    list += "<li>campus: " + this.campusName + "</li><li>building: " + this.buildingCode + "</li><li>times: " + this.times.join(' ') + "</li>";
  });  
});

$('ul').html(list);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/lofimu/1/edit?js,output)

If `root's` has only one element in array

```
var list = '';

$.each(data, function (i, root) {
  list += "<li>campus: " + root[0].campusName + "</li><li>building: " + root[0].buildingCode + "</li><li>times: " + root[0].times.join(' ') + "</li>";
});

$('ul').html(list);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/lofimu/2/edit?js,output)